# VBA: event of sheet change

Tags: excel, vba

Is there an event in VBA that is "sheet change"?
Not `Worksheet_change` but when the user goes from Sheet1 to Sheet2, for instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`Workbook.SheetActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195710.aspx) event.

Place code in the `ThisWorkbook` code module, e.g.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox Sh.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah but this will repeat if the user minimizes excel and then comes back